# Reuse canvas shape instead of writing same code many times

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am currently learning canvas and if I wanted to store my shape and create lets say 4 of them but position them at different locations or with different colors how would I do that?

http://jsfiddle.net/bp0bxgbz/50/

```
var x =  0;
var y = 15;
var speed = 5;

function animate() {

    reqAnimFrame = window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
                window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
                window.oRequestAnimationFrame
                ;

    reqAnimFrame(animate);

    x += speed;

    if(x <= 0 || x >= 475){
        speed = -speed;
    }

    draw();
}


function draw() {
    var canvas  = document.getElementById("ex1");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 170);
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(x,y);
    context.lineTo(x + 105,y + 25);
    context.lineTo(x+25,y+105);
    context.fillStyle="red";
    context.fill();
}

animate();
```

Answer (score 1):

Create 4 objects--one for each triangle.

Each object holds the current x,y position and the current speed for its 1 triangle.

You can use the information inside any 1 object in the draw() function to draw that 1 triangle at its current x,y position.

In the animation function you can use the information inside each of the 4 objects to change the x position of each triangle.

```
var shapes=[];
shapes.push({x:10,y:10,speed:2});
shapes.push({x:10,y:125,speed:4});
shapes.push({x:10,y:250,speed:6});
shapes.push({x:10,y:375,speed:8});
```

In the animation loop, iterate through the array and draw each of the 4 objects by feeding them individually into the draw function.

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 170);

for(var i=0; i<shapes.length;i++){
    var s=shapes[i];
    s.x+=s.speed;
    if(s.x <= 0 || s.x >= 475){
        s.speed*=-1;
    }
    draw(s);
}
```

The draw function should take the specified object and draw according to its specified x,y & speed values.

```
// create canvas & context variables once at the beginning of the script
var canvas  = document.getElementById("ex1");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

function draw(s) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(s.x,s.y);
    context.lineTo(s.x + 105,s.y + 25);
    context.lineTo(s.x+25,s.y+105);
    context.fillStyle="red";
    context.fill();
}
```

Note: you can create the canvas & context variables once at the beginning of your script.  No need to recreate those variables with each call to draw. Also, if all the drawings will be red-filled, then you could set that once at the beginning of the script, too.

Example code and a Demo:

```js
var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var shapes=[];
shapes.push({x:10,y:10,speed:2,color:'red'});
shapes.push({x:10,y:125,speed:4,color:'green'});
shapes.push({x:10,y:250,speed:6,color:'blue'});
shapes.push({x:10,y:375,speed:8,color:'gold'});

animate();

function animate(){
  context.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  for(var i=0; i<shapes.length;i++){
    var s=shapes[i];
    s.x+=s.speed;
    if(s.x <= 0 || s.x >= cw){
      s.speed*=-1;
    }
    draw(s);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function draw(s) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(s.x,s.y);
  context.lineTo(s.x + 105,s.y + 25);
  context.lineTo(s.x+25,s.y+105);
  context.fillStyle=s.color
  context.fill();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=450></canvas>
```

Comment: Wow that is complex. Can you create a jsfiddle so I can play around with it?

Comment: I mean I just didnt understand the part with 4 objects.

Comment: Not so complex after you get used to the idea that you can store the information about your 4 triangles each inside a separate javascript object. Then you can use the information in each object to draw the triangle and change its X position to animate it across the canvas. I further explained the objects and I added a demo to my answer. Good luck with your project!

Comment: should I also read about object oriented programming? I read alot about variables, for loops, while loops, functions, conditionals.

Comment: why s=shapes and not just shapes? Also why did you store the for loop in a var. If I take away it also works

Comment: and one last question why * in s.speed*=-1; ?

Comment: (1) Yes, study OO programming because it allows flexible code reuse--think of it as functionality plus state (data) packed in a reusable box. (2) s=shapes for performance reasons. Looking up a variable is faster than looking up an array element. (3) s.speed*=-1 is the same as your original code, just a bit shorter. I prefer it because if I'm quickly reviewing code I can immediately see that s.speed is being modified by a constant (that way I don't have to mentally seek out s.speed on the right side of the equation). Good luck with your project!